# ZSH: Escaped space chars in command args variable

Tags: bash, zsh

I transitioned from bash to zsh recently and found that some basic stuff appears to work differently. I'm on Mac OSX.

In my bash profile, I had this:

```
alias rununit='python -m pytest --no-cov tests/unit --disable-pytest-warnings --durations=1 --show-capture=no'
export short='--tb=short -qqq'
```

Then I could run `rununit $short` and it would run pytest with the additional args in `$short`. This works fine in bash, but it breaks in zsh. Apparently the space between `short` and `-qqq` is getting escaped, so pytest interprets the value of `tb` arg as `short -qqq` which obviously breaks things.

Is there any way to make this handy shortcut work in zsh?

Comment: I assume `rununit` is an alias, not a parameter.

Comment: The details are a little different with zsh, but [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) generally holds.

Comment: @chepner you are correct, whoops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` does not apply word-splitting to a parameter expansion by default, so `rununit $short` behaves the same as `rununit "$short"`.

Make `short` an array instead. (It does not need to be exported.) I would make `rununit` a function as well.

```
rununit () {
  python -m pytest --no-cov tests/unit --disable-pytest-warnings --durations=1 --show-capture=no
}

short=(--tb=short -qqq)
```

Because of how `zsh` handles parameter expansions, this will make `rununit $short` behave the same as `rununit "${short[@]}"` (which is what you should use in `bash` as well).

---

Or, make `short` an option that the function `rununit` processes to add additional options to your command:

```
rununit () {
  args=(--no-cov tests/unit --dsiable-pytest-warnings --durations=1 --show-capture=no)
  if [[ $1 = short ]]; then
      args+=(--tb=short -qqq)
  fi
  
  python -m pytest $args
}
```

Now you can run `rununit` or `rununit short`.

Comment: Making an array fixed the probem, thanks! It was in fact an alias (whoops, copy-paste error) but making a function is also a good idea. Thanks!